# How can I turn all my 'perform_later's into 'perform_now's locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, jobs

I'm working on a product that calls of `perform_later` jobs. This works for our product in production because we have a series of workers who will run all the jobs.

But, when I'm using the app locally, I don't have access to these workers, and I'd like to change all the `perform_later`s into `perform_now`s *only when* I use the app locally.

What's the best way to do this? One idea I had was to add something in my `env` file that would add a variable to make all `perform_later`s into `perform_now`s -- but I'm not sure what a flag or variable like that would look like.

Ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your app you can have:

*/my_app/config/initializers/jobs_initializer.rb*

```
module JobsExt
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def perform_later(*args)
      puts "I'm on #{Rails.env} envirnoment. So, I'll run right now"
      perform_now(*args)
    end
  end
end

if Rails.env != "production"
  puts "including mixin"
  ActiveJob::Base.send(:include, JobsExt)
end
```

> This mixin will be included on `test` and `development` environments only.

Then, if you have the job in:

*/my_app/app/jobs/my_job.rb*

```
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform(param)
    "I'm a #{param}!"
  end
end
```

You can execute:

```
MyJob.perform_later("job")
```

And get:

```
#=> "I'm a job!"
```

Instead of the job instance:

```
#<MyJob:0x007ff197cd1938 @arguments=["job"], @job_id="aab4dbfb-3d57-4f6d-8994-065a178dc09a", @queue_name="default">
```

> Remember: Doing this, **ALL** your Jobs will be executed right now on test and dev environments. If you want to enable this functionality for a single job, you will need to include the `JobsExt` mixin in that job only.

Comment: Thanks! Nicely documented and easy to read -- thanks for taking the time to write this up.

Comment: acoravos you should mark this answer as correct so @Leantraxxx gets credit.

Answer (score 16):

The clean solution is to change [queue_adapter](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters/InlineAdapter.html) in development environment.

In your `config/environments/development.rb` you need to add:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :inline
end
```

> "When enqueueing jobs with the Inline adapter the job will be executed immediately."

Answer (score 2):

We solved this by calling an intermediate method which then called perform_later or perform_now depending on Rails config:

```
def self.perform(*args)
  if Rails.application.config.perform_later
    perform_later(*args)
  else
    perform_now(*args)
  end
end
```

And simply updated environments configs accordingly